# problems with retopology

Tags: topology

I have done every setting i could, and started to retopology. but i get those holes on my mesh! problem seems to solved only when i increase the number of subsurf modifier like the pictures . Anyone can help me solved this?i also increase the offset value to 0.02 but i still get some holes... [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't solve this issue without further increasing of SS level. Other thing worth trying is to limit original mesh visibility to Wire or retopolgy mesh to X-ray.

Comment: by saying ss level you mean offset?

Comment: SS level is a Subsurf 's number of subdivisions. Shrinkwrap offset won't help if there is significant lack of geometry to wrap original mesh curvature.

Comment: why are these holes a problem? It's normal that some faces will cross the other topology. Also, why have you chosen Shrinkwrap rather than the simple Snap option for your retopology?

Comment: snap option for retopology what is that sir?

Comment: also how much subsurf should i go to? 2 is ok? or more?